# Segmentation fault on loading structure from file in C

Tags: c++

I was playing with C/'s fopen() and putc() functions and wanted to implement serialization/deserialization of a structure. However, here some "Segmentation fault" error occurs. I investigated similar questions and found, that it happens when I am trying to access some memory that doesn't belong to me.

What should I fix in my code to make it work properly?

```
struct Account {
string holder_name;
string holder_password;
double current_sum;
};

int save_to_file(Account * account);
Account * load_from_file(string holder_name);

int main(){
    Account account = { "BEN", "password", 200.0 }; 
    save_to_file(&account);
    load_from_file("BEN");
    return 0;
}

int save_to_file(Account * account){
    const char * cstr = account->holder_name.c_str();
    int size = sizeof(struct Account);

    FILE * fp = fopen(cstr, "wb");
    char * c;

    c = (char *) account;

   for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
   {
       putc(*c++, fp);
   }   

   return fclose(fp);
}

Account * load_from_file(string holder_name)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;
    int i;
    int size = sizeof(struct Account);
    struct Account * ptr = (struct Account *) malloc(sizeof(struct Account));

    if ((fp = fopen(holder_name.c_str(), "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error occured while opening file");
        return NULL;
    }

    c = (char *)ptr;

    while ((i = getc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        *c = i;
        c++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Pick a language `.c_str()` is a C++ `std::string` operator.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You probably want to use formatting I/O (i.e. `<<` and `>>`) rather than trying to copy the storage of types such as `std::string`.  Oh, and prefer `new` and `delete` over `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `string` type doesn't belongs to C language, it's a object that comes from C++.

Since it may be implemented with pointers inside the object, you can't simply write their binary values to a file : the pointed memory won't be allocated when you'll read the file later.

A simple rule is that writing a pointer value to a file is a probably a mistake.

For your code to work, simply replace the `string` type with a `char []`. Here is the code with this only modification :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Account {
    char holder_name[100];
    char holder_password[100];
    double current_sum;
};

int save_to_file(struct Account * account);
struct Account * load_from_file(char *holder_name);

int main(){
   struct Account account = { "BEN", "password", 200.0 }; 
   save_to_file(&account);
   load_from_file("BEN");
   return 0;
}

int save_to_file(struct Account * account){
   const char * cstr = account->holder_name;
   int size = sizeof(struct Account);

   FILE * fp = fopen(cstr, "wb");
   char * c;

   c = (char *) account;

   for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
   {
       putc(*c++, fp);
   }   

   return fclose(fp);
}

struct Account * load_from_file(char *holder_name)
{
   FILE * fp;
   char *c;
   int i;
   int size = sizeof(struct Account);
   struct Account * ptr = (struct Account *) malloc(sizeof(struct Account));

   if ((fp = fopen(holder_name, "rb")) == NULL)
   {
       perror("Error occured while opening file");
       return NULL;
   }

   c = (char *)ptr;

   while ((i = getc(fp))!=EOF)
   {
       *c = i;
       c++;
   }

   fclose(fp);
   return ptr;
}
```